# How to simulate a fresh install?

Tags: ios, xcode

My app crashes when downloaded from the App Store, but never while executed from Xcode.
A bit of background...
Im developing an app that access the Contacts of the user. The app downloads phone numbers from my server and it checks the name of that contact.
I have executed the app one billion times and it never crashes, but I uploaded it to the apple store and it crashes, I looked at the crash log and it crashes while checking the name of the contact, on the method `ABCMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex`, I can't replicate that on Xcode, I try to uninstall the app, but it never crashes! It is the same code, no doubt about it.

So the thing is, something is different when the app is "Freshly" installed in the phone, but I cannot replicate that "new" state.

How could I do that? It never asks me if I let the app access my contacts...

Answer (score 0):

> How to simulate a fresh install?

For this, you simply need to delete your app from the device, then run it again. It will be "freshly" installed. Also, do not forget to do a clean of your project, so that it is built up from scratch.

In any case, it is more likely that your issue comes from a different iOS version on the device compared to the one you are testing against. If you provide some code around the call to `ABCMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex`, it would help understanding things.

Comment: Im using the same device, for the app store installation and the xcode execution.

Comment: And that's wrong, deleting doesnt simulate the same behaviour as when it is installed from the app store, I've done it many times and still I can't reproduce the same error

Comment: what app is this? is it free? can we check it on a "fresh install" on our devices? I think it would be easier providing some code, though...

Comment: @DavidShaikh: have you tried to clean your project in Xcode? I forgot to mention this, but this can really make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

The only secure method = Reset your device to factory settings.

However, usually it's sufficient to uninstall the application and restart the device.
When speaking about Push notifications, it takes 3 days for them to be removed after uninstallation.
Resetting keychain can be tricky, it is best done from the inside of the app.

Also note that you can usually simulate the same behavior just by changing the names of files/keychain entries (etc.) where you are saving data, thus the data won't be loaded when the app is restarted.

Comment: @DavidShaikh Then paste your code. Fresh install is probably not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Keychain to store anything then deleting the app won't clear those entries. If you have nothing tied to your Bundle Id, i.e. Push notifications, you can change the Bundle Id to something else, to run it as a new app

Obviously you'll need to change it back once you've worked out the issue